# How to store a file in struts 2 application folder?

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, struts2

I am using this link   [file upload](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/) for file uploading. But it is giving me **temporary** location for file. but i want to store in **my application folder.** please share your view on this.

Comment: Check this link http://debrajmallick.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/struts2-file-upload-to-desire-folder-location/

Comment: This save  file to build -> web -> myfolder location of  my application. but i want to store in  Web Content folder of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the struts fileupload tag

```
<s:file name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" />
```

In the action class

```
    File fileUpload;
    String fileUploadContentType;
    String fileUploadFileName;
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

Write this Method create a /Upload/Document folder in webcontent

```
private String saveDocumentDoc()
    {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/Upload/Document/");

    System.out.println("Server Path "+filePath);

    Date d = new Date();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("Document");
    String s=stringBuilder.toString();
    File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, s);  

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(this.fileUpload, fileToCreate);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return s;
}
```

Hope it Helps Enjoy